# MSVC does not find symbols during debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, symbols

ALL,

I have a very weird issue.

[image]

This picture shows it. It says that the symbols for the library are not found, but the debugging window clearly indicate that the pdb files are there.

This is on MSVC 2017 Community Edition (a free one) on Windows 8.1.

Could someone please tell me what am I missing?

TIA!

[EDIT]

Please refer to the following screenshot:

[image]

[EDIT2]

This is all pdb's found in the directory:

```
C:\Users\Igor\OneDrive\Documents\dbhandler_app\dbhandler\vc_mswuddll>dir *.pdb
 Volume in drive C is TI10707700A
 Volume Serial Number is AE57-21A1

 Directory of C:\Users\Igor\OneDrive\Documents\dbhandler_app\dbhandler\vc_mswudd
ll

06/06/2019  09:06 AM    <DIR>          ActXPrxy.pdb
09/22/2018  10:52 AM    <DIR>          advapi32.pdb
12/01/2018  11:39 AM    <DIR>          api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.pdb
12/01/2018  11:38 AM    <DIR>          api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.pdb
12/01/2018  11:38 AM    <DIR>          api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.pdb
12/01/2018  11:38 AM    <DIR>          api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.pdb
12/01/2018  11:38 AM    <DIR>          api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.pdb
12/01/2018  11:38 AM    <DIR>          api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.pdb
12/01/2018  11:38 AM    <DIR>          api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.pdb
12/01/2018  11:38 AM    <DIR>          api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.pdb
12/01/2018  11:38 AM    <DIR>          api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.pdb
12/01/2018  11:38 AM    <DIR>          api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.pdb
12/01/2018  11:38 AM    <DIR>          api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.pdb
12/01/2018  11:39 AM    <DIR>          api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.pdb
09/24/2018  09:30 AM    <DIR>          apphelp.pdb
09/27/2018  12:01 PM    <DIR>          atlthunk.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          audiodev.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          Bcp47Langs.pdb
09/27/2018  11:52 AM    <DIR>          bcrypt.pdb
09/22/2018  10:52 AM    <DIR>          bcryptprimitives.pdb
09/27/2018  11:51 AM    <DIR>          cfgmgr32.pdb
09/27/2018  11:51 AM    <DIR>          CLBCatQ.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          ClusApi.pdb
06/06/2019  06:49 AM    <DIR>          combase.pdb
06/06/2019  06:49 AM    <DIR>          comctl32.pdb
09/24/2018  07:39 PM    <DIR>          comdlg32.pdb
09/27/2018  11:52 AM    <DIR>          crypt32.pdb
09/22/2018  10:52 AM    <DIR>          cryptbase.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          cryptdll.pdb
09/27/2018  11:55 AM    <DIR>          cryptsp.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          cscapi.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          davclnt.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          davhlpr.pdb
09/27/2018  12:00 PM    <DIR>          dbghelp.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          DevDispItemProvider.pdb
09/27/2018  11:51 AM    <DIR>          devobj.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          dlnashext.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          dnsapi.pdb
06/09/2019  11:19 AM         7,401,472 docview.pdb
09/27/2018  11:52 AM    <DIR>          dpapi.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          drprov.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          dsparse.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          DUI70.pdb
09/27/2018  12:01 PM    <DIR>          DUser.pdb
09/27/2018  11:50 AM    <DIR>          dwmapi.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          ExplorerFrame.pdb
09/22/2018  10:57 AM    <DIR>          fltLib.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          fwpuclnt.pdb
06/06/2019  09:06 AM    <DIR>          gdiplus.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          globinputhost.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          IconCodecService.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          instapi.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          iphlpapi.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          KERBEROS.pdb
09/27/2018  11:50 AM    <DIR>          Kernel.Appcore.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          linkinfo.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          logoncli.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          mpr.pdb
09/27/2018  11:52 AM    <DIR>          msasn1.pdb
09/22/2018  10:53 AM    <DIR>          msctf.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          msftedit.pdb
09/24/2018  07:39 PM    <DIR>          msimg32.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          mssprxy.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          msv1_0.pdb
09/22/2018  10:49 AM    <DIR>          msvcp140d.i386.pdb
09/27/2018  11:52 AM    <DIR>          msvcr100.i386.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          msvcr80.i386.pdb
09/22/2018  10:52 AM    <DIR>          msvcrt.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          mswsock.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          ncrypt.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          ncryptsslp.pdb
09/27/2018  11:52 AM    <DIR>          netapi32.pdb
02/07/2019  11:26 AM    <DIR>          netbios.pdb
09/27/2018  11:52 AM    <DIR>          netutils.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          NetworkExplorer.pdb
09/27/2018  11:51 AM    <DIR>          nsi.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          ntasn1.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          ntdsapi.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          ntlanman.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          ntshrui.pdb
09/27/2018  11:51 AM    <DIR>          ODBC32.pdb
09/27/2018  11:52 AM    <DIR>          ODBCCP32.pdb
06/06/2019  06:49 AM    <DIR>          ole32.pdb
09/24/2018  07:39 PM    <DIR>          oleacc.pdb
06/06/2019  06:49 AM    <DIR>          oleaut32.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          PlayToDevice.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          PortableDeviceApi.pdb
09/27/2018  11:55 AM    <DIR>          profapi.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          propsys.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          rasadhlp.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          resutils.pdb
09/27/2018  11:55 AM    <DIR>          rsaenh.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          schannel.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          SearchFolder.pdb
09/22/2018  10:52 AM    <DIR>          sechost.pdb
09/27/2018  11:51 AM    <DIR>          secur32.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          security.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          setupapi.pdb
09/27/2018  11:50 AM    <DIR>          shcore.pdb
06/06/2019  06:49 AM    <DIR>          shell32.pdb
09/24/2018  07:39 PM    <DIR>          shlwapi.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          SkyDriveShell.pdb
09/27/2018  11:52 AM    <DIR>          sqlncli11.pdb
09/27/2018  11:52 AM    <DIR>          srvcli.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          StructuredQuery.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          sxs.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          thumbcache.pdb
09/27/2018  11:51 AM    <DIR>          tiptsf.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          twinapi.appcore.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          twinapi.pdb
12/01/2018  11:39 AM    <DIR>          ucrtbase.pdb
09/22/2018  10:50 AM    <DIR>          ucrtbased.pdb
12/01/2018  11:38 AM    <DIR>          vcruntime140.i386.pdb
09/22/2018  10:50 AM    <DIR>          vcruntime140d.i386.pdb
09/22/2018  10:47 AM    <DIR>          verifier.pdb
09/22/2018  10:53 AM    <DIR>          version.pdb
06/06/2019  06:49 AM    <DIR>          wgdi32.pdb
09/22/2018  10:53 AM    <DIR>          wimm32.pdb
06/06/2019  09:06 AM    <DIR>          Windows.Globalization.pdb
06/06/2019  09:06 AM    <DIR>          WindowsCodecs.pdb
09/27/2018  11:51 AM    <DIR>          winmm.pdb
09/27/2018  11:51 AM    <DIR>          winmmbase.pdb
09/27/2018  11:53 AM    <DIR>          winnsi.pdb
06/06/2019  06:49 AM    <DIR>          winspool.pdb
02/08/2019  11:52 AM    <DIR>          winsta.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          wintrust.pdb
06/06/2019  06:49 AM    <DIR>          wkernel32.pdb
06/06/2019  06:49 AM    <DIR>          wkernelbase.pdb
09/27/2018  11:52 AM    <DIR>          wkscli.pdb
12/01/2018  11:38 AM    <DIR>          wldap32.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          WMASF.pdb
09/22/2018  10:47 AM    <DIR>          wntdll.pdb
02/08/2019  11:53 AM    <DIR>          wpdshext.pdb
06/06/2019  06:49 AM    <DIR>          wrpcrt4.pdb
09/27/2018  11:51 AM    <DIR>          ws2_32.pdb
09/27/2018  11:51 AM    <DIR>          wsock32.pdb
09/22/2018  10:52 AM    <DIR>          wsspicli.pdb
09/22/2018  10:52 AM    <DIR>          wuser32.pdb
09/24/2018  07:39 PM    <DIR>          wUxTheme.pdb
04/13/2019  01:41 PM        13,422,592 wxbase311ud_vc_custom.pdb
04/13/2019  02:35 PM         3,969,024 wxbase311ud_xml_vc_custom.pdb
04/13/2019  02:28 PM        15,716,352 wxmsw311ud_adv_vc_custom.pdb
04/13/2019  02:03 PM        29,126,656 wxmsw311ud_core_vc_custom.pdb
09/27/2018  12:01 PM    <DIR>          XmlLite.pdb
               5 File(s)     69,636,096 bytes
             139 Dir(s)  288,268,980,224 bytes free
```

See any problems?

[/EDIT2]

Comment: It doesn't say "not found" nor does it say anything about pdb files.  I'm guessing the real problem is Tools > Options > Debugging > General, "Just my code" should be unticked.

Comment: @HansPassant, it is unchecked. And the picture clearly says `pdb not included`

Comment: @Igor 1. Hi friend, does it make difference if you check the `Microsoft Symbol Servers` and choose `load all modules, unless excluded`. 2. Then you can check the `Modules(Debug=>Windows=>Modules)`window during debug mode, make sure the assembly is loaded exactly. 3. Also, please check if the program you debug comes from `Optimization disabled` setting.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT, where is `Microsoft Symbol Server` located? An optimization is off - this is debug build of the program...

Comment: It locates at Debug menu=>Options=>Symbols. If we enable it, it will download corresponding symbol files from the Internet. Same issue after you tried 1&2&3?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT, No it didn't. When I open the `Modules` window I see `Cannot find or open the PDB file`. Any other ideas?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT, please see the second screenshot. pdb files are there but it looks like they are not

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It seems your assemblies doesn't come from Microsoft, so the server can't help downloading them from Internet. I've checked your screenshot and I'm wondering the relationship between the wxmsw311ud_core_vc_custom.dll and wxbase311ud_vc_custom.dll. Cause the latter one's pdb doesn't exist in the folder and maybe the there has dependency relationship between these two assemblies.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT, I added the whole list of pdb's from that directory to the OP. Se any issues?

Comment: @Igor Hi , It looks everything is right but the issue just happens. Have you checked the file version? From your first pic, it looks for the 3.01.1.0 version, the same you have in that folder?  I'm confused why you have same assemblies specified in the modules window(in both lib and one-drive), try deleting the four modules in lib folder and check if it helps.

Comment: Also, it's [one good reply](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e55d2f23-4803-45a9-995d-77b461e23273/skipped-loading-symbols?forum=vsdebug) about how such error may occurs though it's old.